# Python Regex findall() returning empty keys

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to capture a couple of groups messages in a text with regex findall() but I always end up with empty values in the capture, that are not present if I use every single regex pattern separated, so I suspect findall() is the root cause of this behaviour:

**input text:**

```text
ACCESSPOINT01#show inter dot 0
Load for 1 min: 1.06, 5 min: 1.12, 15 min: 1.13
Date: *05:29:05 UTC Mon Jul 24 2023

Dot11Radio0 is UP, line protocol is UP
Hardware is 802.11 2.4G Radio, channel is 11
Radio MAC is F4:xx:yy:zz:1E:40

Dot11Radio0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F4:xx:yy:zz:1E:40  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:88943849 errors:0 dropped:189 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4471475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:294364122 (280.7 MiB)  TX bytes:336905236 (321.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:65 Memory:f8000000-f8200000 

        DOT11 Statistics (Cumulative Total/Last 5 Seconds):
RECEIVER                                TRANSMITTER
Host Rx K Bytes:         20931/0        Host Tx K Bytes:        188148/0
Unicasts Rx:            113976/0        Unicasts Tx:            189770/0
Broadcasts Rx:             253/0        Broadcasts Tx:               0/0
Beacons Rx:           69666326/117      Beacons Tx:           85507736/98
Probes Rx:             4115902/4        Probes Tx:             1075910/0
Multicasts Rx:            1744/0        Multicasts Tx:               0/0
Mgmt Packets Rx:      73769674/121      Mgmt Packets Tx:           350/0
Ctrl Frames Rx:        4060958/0        Ctrl Frames Tx:          79794/0
RTS received:           742661/0        RTS transmitted:         20579/0
Duplicate frames:            0/0        CTS not received:         6662/0
MIC errors:                  0/0        WEP errors:                  0/0
FCS errors:           13657410/5        Retries:                 30434/0
Key Index errors:         8161/0        Tx Failures:             17482/0
                                        Tx Drops:                  100/0

Rate Statistics for Radio::
[Legacy]:
6 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        210/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:         69/0
18 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        107/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0
24 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        129/0            Tx Packets:        127/0
                                     Tx Retries:         18/0
1 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        104/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0
5.5 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:         53/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0

[SU]:
M0:
 Rx Packets:        307/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0
M1:
 Rx Packets:         88/0            Tx Packets:         41/0
                                     Tx Retries:         54/0
M2:
 Rx Packets:        204/0            Tx Packets:         28/0
                                     Tx Retries:         62/0
M3:
 Rx Packets:        827/0            Tx Packets:        189/0
                                     Tx Retries:        175/0
M4:
 Rx Packets:       1821/0            Tx Packets:       1310/0
                                     Tx Retries:        620/0
M5:
 Rx Packets:       1163/0            Tx Packets:       5219/0
                                     Tx Retries:       2299/0
M6:
 Rx Packets:       2589/0            Tx Packets:      28293/0
                                     Tx Retries:       6406/0
M7:
 Rx Packets:     108325/0            Tx Packets:     154563/0
                                     Tx Retries:      20731/0



Beacons missed: 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+
                     0      0      0    0

Vap TX statistics:
vap      ssid  MGMT      Beacon     DATA     [BK      BE  VI   VO] Bytes(Data) QosRetries AMDPU-SubFrameRetries
  2  GuestNet 347/0 42751408/48 189760/0 99145/0 90498/0 0/0 117/0 192659307/0    30432/0                   0/0
  3 DeviceNet   3/0 42756424/48     10/0     0/0     0/0 0/0  10/0      4329/0        2/0                   0/0

Vap RX statistics:
vap      ssid  MGMT     DATA   [BK       BE    VI  VO] Bytes(Data)
  2  GuestNet 543/0 115927/0 151/0 113362/0 422/0 52/0  21432778/0
  3 DeviceNet  18/0      9/0   0/0      0/0   0/0  9/0       637/0




ACCESSPOINT01#show inter dot 1
Load for 1 min: 1.05, 5 min: 1.12, 15 min: 1.13
Date: *05:29:08 UTC Mon Jul 24 2023

Dot11Radio1 is UP, line protocol is UP
Hardware is 802.11 5.0G Radio, channel is 64
Radio MAC is F4:xx:yy:zz:1E:40

Dot11Radio1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F4:xx:yy:zz:1E:40  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:114784169 errors:0 dropped:835 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94799029 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3284042594 (3.0 GiB)  TX bytes:3559168106 (3.3 GiB)
          Interrupt:102 Memory:f8400000-f8600000 

        DOT11 Statistics (Cumulative Total/Last 5 Seconds):
RECEIVER                                TRANSMITTER
Host Rx K Bytes:      79607258/0        Host Tx K Bytes:     101832626/0
Unicasts Rx:          73715624/0        Unicasts Tx:          96438538/0
Broadcasts Rx:           28734/0        Broadcasts Tx:         1652718/5
Beacons Rx:             203978/0        Beacons Tx:          128198404/144
Probes Rx:              388593/0        Probes Tx:              824009/0
Multicasts Rx:          313967/0        Multicasts Tx:         5525078/8
Mgmt Packets Rx:       1542440/0        Mgmt Packets Tx:        146786/4
Ctrl Frames Rx:       66598283/0        Ctrl Frames Tx:       49372271/0
RTS received:          9451009/0        RTS transmitted:      14920090/0
Duplicate frames:            0/0        CTS not received:       998703/0
MIC errors:                  0/0        WEP errors:                  0/0
FCS errors:             389832/0        Retries:              35360788/0
Key Index errors:       128994/0        Tx Failures:          23306795/0
                                        Tx Drops:               209869/0

Rate Statistics for Radio::
[Legacy]:
6 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:      26080/0            Tx Packets:          2/0
                                     Tx Retries:       1093/0
18 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        704/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0
24 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:       2141/0            Tx Packets:       4320/0
                                     Tx Retries:        165/0
36 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        554/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0
48 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        394/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0
54 Mbps:
 Rx Packets:        850/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:          0/0

[SU]:
M0:
 Rx Packets:      17034/0            Tx Packets:     354337/0
                                     Tx Retries:      17074/0
M1:
 Rx Packets:      29096/0            Tx Packets:      36755/0
                                     Tx Retries:     127215/0
M2:
 Rx Packets:      42855/0            Tx Packets:      82986/0
                                     Tx Retries:     231767/0
M3:
 Rx Packets:      55170/0            Tx Packets:     339425/0
                                     Tx Retries:     107398/0
M4:
 Rx Packets:      82253/0            Tx Packets:    1698006/0
                                     Tx Retries:     398620/0
M5:
 Rx Packets:     228984/0            Tx Packets:    3491802/0
                                     Tx Retries:    1265598/0
M6:
 Rx Packets:     236915/0            Tx Packets:   14587013/0
                                     Tx Retries:    3532183/0
M7:
 Rx Packets:    2283900/0            Tx Packets:   44115505/0
                                     Tx Retries:   10928276/0

[MU]:
M6:
 Rx Packets:          0/0            Tx Packets:        336/0
                                     Tx Retries:         29/0
M7:
 Rx Packets:          0/0            Tx Packets:        122/0
                                     Tx Retries:       1374/0
M8:
 Rx Packets:          0/0            Tx Packets:          1/0
                                     Tx Retries:       1754/0
M9:
 Rx Packets:          0/0            Tx Packets:          0/0
                                     Tx Retries:        640/0



Beacons missed: 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+
                     0      0      0    0

Vap TX statistics:
vap      ssid     MGMT      Beacon         DATA       [BK         BE         VI       VO] Bytes(Data) QosRetries AMDPU-SubFrameRetries
  1   CorpNet 100502/4 42723779/48 103112436/13 3958248/0 75641513/0 26490942/0 3089510/0 587050666/0 35222485/0                   0/0
  2  GuestNet  25675/0 42737305/48     472136/0  233805/0   238177/0        0/0      57/0 568646631/0   133086/0                   0/0
  3 DeviceNet  20609/0 42737320/48      31762/0     130/0    31492/0        0/0     135/0  41697610/0     5217/0                   0/0

Vap RX statistics:
vap      ssid     MGMT       DATA   [BK         BE         VI       VO]  Bytes(Data)
  1   CorpNet 945009/0 73834778/0 389/0 49220485/0 44389340/0 1734043/0 4175456208/0
  2  GuestNet   4623/0   216838/0  11/0   214868/0        0/0      18/0   30930977/0
  3 DeviceNet    468/0     6179/0 102/0     5524/0        0/0       0/0    2034118/0
```

**script:**

```
re_patterns = [
    '(Dot11Radio[0-2])\sis\s(UP|DOWN).+(UP|DOWN)$',
    '(Beacons missed:)(.+?)$\n\s+(.+?)$'
]

generic_re = re.compile( r'|'.join( re_patterns), re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE )
beacons = (re.findall(generic_re, itext))

print(accesspoints['host'])
print (*beacons)
```

**output:**

```text
ACCESSPOINT01
('Dot11Radio0', 'UP', 'UP', '', '', '') ('', 'Beacons missed:', ' 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+', '0      0      0    0') ('Dot11Radio1', 'UP', 'UP', '', '', '') ('', 'Beacons missed:', ' 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+', '198      6      0    0')
```

**expected output:**

```text
ACCESSPOINT01
('Dot11Radio0', 'UP', 'UP') ('Beacons missed:', ' 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+', '0      0      0    0') ('Dot11Radio1', 'UP', 'UP') ('Beacons missed:', ' 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+', '198      6      0    0')
```

In addition to that, how can I print the capture groups so I get something similar to the input text?

```text
ACCESSPOINT01
    Dot11Radio0 UP/UP
        Beacons missed:
            0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+
            0      0      0    0

    Dot11Radio1 UP/UP
        Beacons missed:
            0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+
            198      6      0    0
```

Comment: you have no lookarounds in your regexp. Why did you use that tag?

Comment: check this and edit your question accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There are six capturing groups in the regex, and whenever the regex matches, three of them do not capture anything (because they are on the side of `|` that wasn't chosen). Why is the result surprising?

Comment: "In addition to that" - sorry; we require **one** question per post here - what you describe is a completely separate task, which itself logically breaks down into a series of steps. Please try to write code for it - there is no special shortcut for the output you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the regexp contains capture groups, `re.findall()` returns a list of tuples of all the capture group matches.

You have two alternatives in your regexp, and each of them contains capture groups. If the first alternative matches, the capture groups in the second alternative don't match anything, so you get empty strings for those groups. Conversely, when the second alternative matches, you get empty strings for the capture groups in the first alternative.

So depending on which alternative matches, either the first or last 3 elements of the tuple will be empty strings. This allows you to tell which alternative matched.

If you don't want this, don't put all the alternatives in a single regexp. Match each one separately, and then combine the two results.

```
beacons = []
for pat in re_patterns:
    beacons.extend(re.findall(pat, itext, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.I))
```

BTW, the output you show is not what I get. I get

```
('Dot11Radio0', 'UP', 'UP', '', '', '') ('', '', '', 'Beacons missed:', ' 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+', '0      0      0    0') ('Dot11Radio1', 'UP', 'UP', '', '', '') ('', '', '', 'Beacons missed:', ' 0-30s 31-60s 61-90s 90s+', '0      0      0    0')
```